# Resaltar el primer registro traido de una consulta Mysql con DESC

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

No se si el titulo es lo suficientemente descriptivo, pero no sabía como formularla pregunta. El problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una consulta que la utilizo para mostrar un "top" de las 20 edades de unas personas. Lo que quiero es que el primer registro mostrado, en este caso el que tenga la mayor edad, sea resaltado de alguna manera como para mostrar de que ese el primero. Quizas haya alguna manera de seleccionarlo desde php y luego aplicar el css requerido. Aquí está el código:

```
$sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM personas ORDER BY edad DESC LIMIT 0,20");
foreach ($sel as $datos) {
echo $datos['nombre']."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma más simple de hacerlo con un `foreach` clásico para consultas en `PHP` sería declarar una variable bandera para saber cuando es el primer registro, en la primera iteración ya modificamos a false la bandera y podremos imprimir los valores con el formato normal. *(para el ejemplo utilizo orientado a objetos)*

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "mipassword", "midb");
$sel = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM personas ORDER BY edad DESC LIMIT 0,20");
$primerRegistro= true;
foreach ($sel as $datos) {
  if($primerRegistro){
    echo "<strong>". $datos['nombre']."</strong><br>";
    $primerRegistro= false;//Nos aseguramos que solo se ejecute una vez
  }
  else{
    echo $datos['nombre']."<br>";
  }
}
```

> La otra opción sería un `for` clásico y acceder al primer elemento de
>   `array` `[0]` de datos devuelto por la consulta.

Otra opción para evitar la comprobación de un `if` dentro de un bucle en cada iteración ,  sería obtener los datos fila por fila con el típico método  [`fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

```
$sel = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM personas ORDER BY edad DESC LIMIT 0,20");
//Obtenemos el total de las filas devueltas por la consulta
$total= $sel->num_rows;
if($total>=1){
  //Obtenemos el primer elemento e imprimimos en negrita
  $data = $sel->fetch_array();
  echo "<strong>". $data['nombre']."</strong><br>";
  // Si hubiesen más entra al while si no , no 
  while($data = $sel->fetch_array())
  {
    //Impresión Normal
     echo $data['nombre']."<br>";
  }
}else{
  echo "No Hay Resultados";
}
```

Dejando de lado el tratamiento del primer elemento desde `PHP`, y si solo desea dar estilo al primer elemento , podríamos centrarnos simplemente en reglas `CSS` , incluidas pseudo-clases como [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child).

**PHP**

```
$sel = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM personas ORDER BY edad DESC LIMIT 0,20");
echo "<ol class='misdatos'>";
foreach ($sel as $datos) {
  echo "<li>".$datos['nombre']."</li>";
}
echo "</ol>";
```

obtendrá una lista con la clase `.misdatos` , este sería el selector para el `CSS` obteniendo el primer elemento `li` que encuentre le aplicará el color rojo. *(para el ejemplo, usted decide que reglas aplica)*

```
<style>
.misdatos li:first-child{
  color : red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Dado que el OP hace mención de CSS, y teniendo en cuenta que la práctica actual recomienda manejar los estilos independientemente del contenido en sí, convendría también una respuesta basada en la aplicación de estilos mediante CSS. Creo que sería una solución más adecuada al problema planteado, y mucho más flexible, de hecho, hay reglas CSS para alcanzar el primer elemento de un grupo de elementos cualesquiera, por ejemplo, una tabla, párrafos dentro un div, lis dentro de un ul, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano en efecto sería más sencillo , igual actualicé para las dos opciones, Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Basta con que preguntes en un if si es el primer registro del array

```
for($i=0; $i<count($sel); $i++) {
   if($i==0) {
      //Imprimir destacado EJ: <span class="destacado">$datos['nombre']</span>
      //<i >$datos['nombre']</i>
      echo '<strong>'.$datos['nombre'].'</strong><br>';
   } else {
      echo $datos['nombre'].'<br>';     
}
```

Comment: `$datos` no está disponible en el `for`  o al menos no se ve como lo está obteniendo.