# ¿Cómo agregar un sólo dato sin que se repita en un foreach que tiene varias repeticiones?

Tags: php

Tengo un `foreach` que repite los elementos `li` según los valores de la variable `$channels`, para ser precisos aquella variable tiene datos separados  por comas, por cada dato separado por comas se repite, ejemplo: `$channels="dato,dato2,dato3";` se observa 3 datos separados por comas, por lo cuál el `foreach` hará repetir 3 veces el elemento `li`.

Por lo tanto, El siguiente `foreach` de PHP repite tres veces los elementos `li`.

Quiero agregarle una clase al elemento `li` mediante la siguiente variable: `$myclass = "active";` pero sin que se repita en todos los `li` de los 3 elementos `li` que se van a generar solo quiero que en el primer `li` se agregué la clase o que es lo mismo que solo en el primer li sé imprima la variable `$myclass` como puedo hacerlo?

```
        <?php
            foreach ($channels as $key => $value)
            {   
        ?>
                <li class="item <?php echo $myclass;?>"><span data-target="#<?PHP echo $key;?>">Option <?php echo $key;?></span></li>
        <?php
            }            
        ?>
```

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160167/resaltar-el-primer-registro-traido-de-una-consulta-mysql-con-desc/160171#160171) te puede ayudar para este caso.

Comment: @Dev.Joel siguiendo su ejemplo debería quedar así https://ideone.com/ZPQ8Ju o no?

Comment: Así es, más o menos así debería quedar... pero revisaría también la opción de estilos CSS al final de mi respuesta. ;)

Comment: @Dev.Joel Estupendo lo he logrado https://ideone.com/8ZB0ga mediante su ejemplo gracias :) ahora voy a probar los ejemplos de la respuesta que me han dado :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer una validación al momento de imprimir la clase.

Algo como

```
<?php echo $key === 0 ? $myclass : ''; ?>
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
<?php
foreach ($channels as $key => $value)
{   
?>
    <li class="item <?php echo $key === 0 ? $myclass : ''; ?>"><span data-target="#<?PHP echo $key;?>">Option <?php echo $key;?></span></li>
<?php
}            
?>
```

Esto es asumiendo que la variable $channels es un array con claves numéricas.

En caso de que $channels sea un array con claves asociativas:

```
<?php
$index = 0;
foreach ($channels as $key => $value)
{
?>
    <li class="item <?php echo $index === 0 ? $myclass : ''; ?>"><span data-target="#<?PHP echo $key;?>">Option <?php echo $key;?></span></li>
<?php
    $index++;
}            
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder voy a seguir su ejemplo a ver cómo se ejecuta... Adicional e actualizado mi pregunta sobre la variable `$channels`.

Comment: Estupendo funciona https://ideone.com/RFVI4B :)

Comment: @A.Cedano Observe amigo https://ideone.com/RFVI4B esto era lo que quería, tan simple y sencillo sin salirse fuera del tema, agregar una sola vez dicha clase, ya veo que es mejor no detallar tanto y dejar las preguntas a media para que sean entendidas uf! que día, igual gracias por todo.